Question about the Riemannian connections and metric
Suppose for the Riemannian manifold $M$ we have the Levi-Civita connection as $\nabla^{LC}$ and $g$ be the Riemannian metric. Now my question is suppose for an arbitrary dual connection on the manifold $M$ I have the following expression
$g(\nabla_{X}^{LC}Y,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_{X}^{LC}Z)=\frac{1}{2}\left[g(\nabla_{X}Y,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_{X}Z)+g(\nabla_{X}^{\ast}Y,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_{X}^{\ast}Z)\right]$
so can I compare the left and right hand side and write:
$g(Y,\nabla_{X}^{LC}Z) = \frac{1}{2}[g(Y,\nabla_{X}Z) + g(Y,\nabla_{X}^{\ast}Z)]$
and similar for the $g(\nabla_{X}^{LC}Y,Z)$ here I am comparing as per the coefficients. Please explain.

What is your question?

What do you mean by dual connection? What precisely are $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$?

@TedShifrin the connection $\nabla$ and $\nabla*$ are dual connections they satisfy
$X g(Y,Z)=g (\nabla_{X}Y,Z)+ g(Y,\nabla_{X}^{*}Z)$

@J.V.Gaiter please read I have clearly mention that can we compare the left and right hand terms and write the expression which I have mentioned at the end.
